# Executing powershell script from linux to windows machine

Tags: powershell, openssh, powershell-core

We would like to execute powershell scripts which are located at windows share drive eg: winvmx01\folder1\folder2\script.ps1 from linux machine.
We installed powershell in linux machine and running `Invoke-Command -Computername winvmx01 -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files" }`
but it cant able to find commands of powershell and posting an error `/bin/bash: line 69: Invoke-Command: command not found.`
when we tried to check version it is showing up fine

```
pwsh
PowerShell v6.0.4
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.`
```

can someone please suggest how we can proceed. if not powershell is there any other client that we can use to execute a script in windows shared machine.

Thanks!

Comment: That's a bash error msg, not from pwsh - so either you didn't stay in the invoked pwsh or you didn't pass the arguments properly when invoking pwsh with arguments.

Comment: @LotPings Thanks for your insights. I installed poweshell on linux so, it should be available on that linux machine right? or in bash do we need to initialize poweshell first  and then run pwsh commands. thanks again!